# How to split a string and store in different string array

Tags: c#

if i have a string like

```
string hello="HelloworldHellofriendsHelloPeople";
```

i would like to store this in a string like this

```
Helloworld
Hellofriends
HelloPeople
```

It has to change the line when it finds the string "hello"

thanks

Comment: Do you want a string, or an array?

Answer (score 6):

```
string hello = "HelloworldHellofriendsHelloPeople";
var a = hello.Split(new string[] { "Hello"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in a)
    Console.WriteLine("Hello" + s);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var result = hello.Split(new[] { "Hello" }, 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(s => "Hello" + s);
```

Comment: You beat me into it... hahaha! anyway, I think this is the best answer but since the OP is asking to store it into a string array, adding .ToArray() at the end will do that.

Comment: @pinoy_ISF The OP never asked for the result to be an array.

Comment: @Servy The title says "How to split a string and store in different string array"  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
(?=Hello)
```

and then split the string using regex's `split` method!

Your code would be:

```
      String matchpattern = @"(?=Hello)";
      Regex re = new Regex(matchpattern); 
      String[] splitarray = re.Split(sourcestring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code - based on string.Replace

```
var replace = hello.Replace( "Hello", "-Hello" );
var result = replace.Split("-");
```

Comment: in this case she does contain (string hello="HelloworldHellofriendsHelloPeople";
), Please you can read question before comment

Comment: it's easy to replace with another separator, it's not difficult, and just for this you set downvote ????

Comment: The OP isn't looking for code to parse just that one example input.  If he was then you could just `return new[]{"Helloworld"},"Hellofriends",...}`.  Clearly that's not useful.  Even if you change the separator, the code will always break if the input string contains that separator.  Here the actual delimiter is `Hello`, and the code should act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.split` to split on the word "Hello", and then append "Hello" back onto the string.

```
string[] helloArray = string.split("Hello");
foreach(string hello in helloArray)
{
    hello = "Hello" + hello;
}
```

That will give the output you want of

```
Helloworld
Hellofriends
HelloPeople
```